how can i solve for this error HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.", 400 in azure synapse pyspark
hey guys how can solve for this error i am using synapse to read data from a blob with
Hierarchical namespace Enabled but when i try to write back i get
: Operation failed: "An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.", 400, PUT, https://businessblobtut.blob.core.windows.net/config/config_delta/ADF_CONFIG_TABLES/_delta_log?resource=directory&timeout=90, , ""
file_name = 'config_transport_excel.xlsx'
file_path =f'abfss://config@businessblobtut.blob.core.windows.net/config_excel/{file_name}'
save_path =f'abfss://config@businessblobtut.blob.core.windows.net/config_delta/ADF_CONFIG_TABLES'

pandas_df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
delta_table = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
delta_table.write.format('delta').mode('append').save(save_path)

i want ro read the excel and convert it to delta formart and save withing the same blob

Try the following solution:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd

# Initialize Spark session with ADLS Gen2 configurations
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("ADLS Gen2 Write") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<your-storage-account-access-key>") \
    .getOrCreate()

file_name = 'config_transport_excel.xlsx'
file_path =f'abfss://config@businessblobtut.dfs.core.windows.net/config_excel/{file_name}'
save_path =f'abfss://config@businessblobtut.dfs.core.windows.net/config_delta/ADF_CONFIG_TABLES'

# Read the Excel file into a pandas DataFrame
pandas_df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

# Convert the pandas DataFrame to a Spark DataFrame
delta_table = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

# Write the DataFrame to ADLS Gen2 in Delta format
delta_table.write.format('delta').mode('append').save(save_path)


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
